# How can I print from Windows 10 vm client with no internet connection to Ubuntu 17.10 host?

Tags: printing

I have Ubuntu 17.10 installed on my computer. I have a Windows 10 virtual machine also installed on the computer with KVM/QEMU.  We are not allowing internet connection to Windows 10.  I have a Samba folder connecting the Windows and Linux machines.  There is ping between Linux and Windows 10,  in both directions. I have a usb printer HP LaserJet 1018 connected to the Linux machine and set to print through cups. I want to print from within Windows to this HP LaserJet 1018 printer.
I want the print job to be sent to the Linux host computer that is set up to print through cups.  I followed instructions for connecting a network printer to Windows 10 (http://www.tp-link.com/il/faq-929.html). Since my printer is old, the driver is not on the list and I cannot download it because we are not allowing internet connection to Windows.

Questions:  Does IPP require that a print driver be installed on the client computer when printing through the host?  Can the print job be sent to the host without a driver on the client?  How can I get around this issue so I can install the printer on the Windows 10 client so that a print job can be sent through to the host without installing the driver? I cannot click the ‘Windows Update’ button to download it because I am not allowing the Windows machine to connect to the internet.

Comment: If you do not print too regularly, you could send all your Windows Print jobs to PDF in the VM. Enable Shared folders between Host and Guest and print the PDF file from your linux.

Comment: The client has to have a driver for the printer, local or networked is the same. But HP LasrJet 1018 must use the Windows built-in printer driver in Windows 10: https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01796879 .